# Locker room shower temperature is too hot to enjoy -- is there a good reason?

Tags: pool

What is the right temperature for showers in public places.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the water temperature of showers in a public swimming pool. Please see [help/on-topic] for the types of questions we welcome here.

Comment: Not really a Home Improvement question, but i can't think of a better place to move it to.

Answer (score 1):

The temperature needs to be high enough to kill Legionella and low enough to avoid causing scalding injuries.

In my experience, this is a negative space. To kill Legionella, the water needs to be above 60C.

Check your local laws, they vary from country to country and sometimes within countries.

[UK:](http://www.hse.gov.uk/healthservices/legionella.htm)

> - Hot water storage cylinders (calorifiers) should store water at 60°C or higher
> - Hot water should be distributed at 50°C or higher (thermostatic mixer valves need to be fitted as close as possible to outlets, where a scald risk is identified).